# Word Object Model: Save as Unicode Text

Tags: unicode, ms-word, autohotkey, msdn

I know that it is possible to save a document as text with the Word Object Model. ([MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836084.aspx))

It says in the documentation that the number for Unicode Text is "7", which is why I use the following code in AutoHotkey: `oWord.Documents(1).SaveAs2(SpeicherortB,7)`
(Saves Document 1 of the oWord Application to the location "SpeicherortB" as Unicode (7))

Unlike the documentation suggests, the result is not Unicode though, Asian or Russian characters are not supported. Do you have any idea how to fix this?

For reference: I need to use the Object Model as I am running my code through AutoHotkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MsoEncoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa432511(v=office.12).aspx) parameter has to be set to the number **65001**.

The final AutoHotkey line would thus look like this:

```
oWord.Documents(1).SaveAs2(filename, 7,,,,,,,,,, 65001)
```

Comment: It wasn't possible before, I just did it – thank you for the reminder :)